# Error C3867 in visual c++

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

I'm a beginner to programming....
I when i try to compile this code using visual c++ 2012,Following error shows. 
`1>e:\item(2).cpp(158): error C3867: 'selection::option': function call missing argument list; use '&selection::option' to create a pointer to member`

Please give me a solution

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We can't help you if you don't give us enough information to do so.

Comment: You forgot to post your code...

Comment: Nobody can give you a meaningful "solution" until you provide at least a basic description of a problem. The error message you posted is completely meaningless without the proper context.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0x1aatf.aspx):-

You tried to take the address of a member function without qualifying the member function with its class name and the address-of operator.

You have to qualify the function name with the class name using `::` to get rid of the error:-

You should do this:-

```
    &className::func1
```

instead of

```
    &func1
```

But since, you are a beginner, I presume you might have forgotten to supply arguments to your function call.

Comment: What made you decide that the OP wants take the address of a member function in the first place?

Comment: @AndreyT Check the documentation link.Based on the info provided by OP, we can only make a approximate guess what OP is trying to do.

Comment: Documentation at the link applies to error C3867, which was the compiler's guess at what the OP was trying to do. This compiler's guess is most likely completely off the mark. My guess would be that the OP simply forgot to specify arguments in member function call and the complier wildly misinterpreted the situation. I.e. it has nothing to do with any member function pointers at all.

Comment: @AndreyT I also, guessed the same but then went with the compiler's guess. Anyways edited my answer to include that case also.